# NSLog output from remote testers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm having a difficulty with remote testing. In my app, when I run it from XCode, everything goes fine (the app copy some default resources to the documents and show them from there, the documents folder). Then, I send the IPA to some beta testers but they see nothing (as if the copy from resources to the documents folder in the device did not worked at all).

My question is twofold; first, what might be going on (with the remote testers). Second, I put several NSLogs throughout the app, but the remote devices can’t be connected to my computer (or to a mac with XCode) in order to use Organizer to retrieve the logs. How to I retrieve the logs form the remote testers (maybe using itunes?)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use thirdparty solution like [Bugfender](https://bugfender.com/) which should be free for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just printing an NSLog statement when a network error occurs isn't the same as actually handling the error.

more information refer [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/935488#935488)

Answer (score 0):

The most easy solution is that you should use a 3rd party framework for remote logging and analytics.
Such as [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/),[Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/) or [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/)

All these companies have free sdks that you can include within your project.